# Lost innocence lost the note

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I got the note and I store some of my things including the note in a Chest and when I went back To go get it it wasn't there anymore what can I do ??

Comment: what note and what chest?

Comment: As far as I know lost innocence doesn't have any notes needed for the quest. If you have the quest you can perform it without any specific items. As for notes and chests in general, it's not a good idea to store things in chests in places you don't own, there is no guarantee things in that chest will be there when you return.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the mysterious note with an image of a hand and the words "we know", it is just a warning. It doesn't matter if you lose it. All that matters is that you received the note. You'll find out more if you get a good night's sleep.

Comment: I haven't tried yet but I will when I get back in thanks I'll let you know if it works or doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Just get sleep, as others I see have reccomended. You don't necessarily need the note, lel.